# How to print nested objects parameters in spring boot when using GET method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, controller

Don't know if I managed to phrase if correctly, but basicaly:

- I have an object "Basket" for example, it has 3 fruits and a wallet inside, the wallet containing more objects in itself.
- When printing the Basket after receiving a GET request, I want not only the fruits and the wallet to be printed, but also what is inside the wallet.

```
**What I want:**
[
 {
  "fruit1": "x",
  "fruit2": "y",
  "fruit3" "z",
  "wallet": {
    "item1": "a",
    "item2": "b",
    "item3": "c"}
 }
]

**What I'm getting:**
[
 {
  "fruit1": "x",
  "fruit2": "y",
  "fruit3" "z",
  "wallet": {}
 }
]
```

My code currently is like this:

**Basket model**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BASKETS")
 public class Basket{
  @Id
  private String owner;
  private String fruit1;
  private String fruit2;
  private String fruit3;
  @Embedded
  private Wallet wallet;
}
```

**Wallet model**

```
@Embeddable
public class Wallet{
  private String item1;
  private String item2;
  private String item3;
}
```

**Basket Service**

```
@Service
public class BasketService{

  @Autowired
  private BasketRepository basketRepo;

  public List<Basket> find(){
    return basketRepo.findAll();
  }
}
```

**Basket Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/baskets")
public class BasketController{

 @Autowired
 private BasketRepository basketRepo;

 @Autowired
 private BasketService basketService;

 @Autowired
 private ModdelMapper mapper;

  @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<BasketResponse>> find(){
        var baskets = basketService.find();
        var result = new ArrayList<BasketResponse>();
        for (Basket basket : baskets){
            var basketDTO = mapper.map(basket, BasketResponse.class);
            result.add(basketDTO);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
}
```

I don't know what exactly to change, tried to search for a solution, but probably I don't know how to search for this specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a custom DTO class that represents the structure you want in the response. You can then manually map the data from the Basket and Wallet objects to this DTO.

```
 @Data
public class BasketResponse {
    private String fruit1;
    private String fruit2;
    private String fruit3;
    private WalletResponse wallet;
}

@Data
public class WalletResponse {
    private String item1;
    private String item2;
    private String item3;
}

@Service
public class BasketService {
    @Autowired
    private BasketRepository basketRepo;

    public List<BasketResponse> find() {
        List<Basket> baskets = basketRepo.findAll();
        return baskets.stream().map(this::mapToResponse).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private BasketResponse mapToResponse(Basket basket) {
        BasketResponse basketResponse = new BasketResponse();
        basketResponse.setFruit1(basket.getFruit1());
        basketResponse.setFruit2(basket.getFruit2());
        basketResponse.setFruit3(basket.getFruit3());

        Wallet wallet = basket.getWallet();
        if (wallet != null) {
            WalletResponse walletResponse = new WalletResponse();
            walletResponse.setItem1(wallet.getItem1());
            walletResponse.setItem2(wallet.getItem2());
            walletResponse.setItem3(wallet.getItem3());
            basketResponse.setWallet(walletResponse);
        }

        return basketResponse;
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/baskets")
public class BasketController {
    @Autowired
    private BasketService basketService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<BasketResponse>> find() {
        List<BasketResponse> baskets = basketService.find();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(baskets);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Turns out adding @Data to the Wallet model solved the problem, but it's nice to know a way to do it without depending solely on notations